# Replace one python object with another everywhere

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I replace a python object everywhere with another object?

I have two classes, `SimpleObject` and `FancyObject`. I've created a `SimpleObject`, and have several references to it. Now I'd like to create a `FancyObject`, and make all those references point to the new object.

```
a = SimpleObject()
some_list.append(a)
b = FancyObject()
```

`a = b` is not what I want, it just changes what a points to. I read the following would work, but doesn't. I get an error "Attribute __dict__ is not writable":

```
a.__dict__ = b.__dict__
```

What I want is the equivalent of (pseudo-C):

```
*a = *b
```

I know this is hacky, but is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: So, you want to change what data is stored in the place where `a` is stored? I'll post an answer after lunch..

Comment: @Schoolboy Yes. Basically I've put a simple object in a, and would like to (lazily) promote it to a more complex object b when the need arises. a and b have the same interface, so code using them should be able to handle this.

Comment: For reference, if anyone stumbles across this, Smalltalk has precisely this functionality --- the `become:` method. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290908/what-uses-does-smalltalk-s-become-have

Answer (score 2):

There's no way. It'd let you mutate immutable objects and cause all sorts of nastiness.

```
x = 1
y = (x,)
z = {x: 3}
magic_replace(x, [1])
# x is now a list!
# The contents of y have changed, and z now has an unhashable key.

x = 1 + 1
# Is x 2, or [1, 1], or something stranger?
```

Comment: Well, the contents of `y`,`z` won't change, as they refer to what `x` was referring to earlier.. The only thing that's changed is what `x` refers to. (Correct me if I'm wrong, as I don't know C).

Comment: If you only want to change what the name `x` refers to, `x = whatever` is what you're after. If you want to magically replace the object `x` was referring to with a new object, that'd have to be visible everywhere that used the old object, including dicts and tuples.

Comment: @Schoolboy but that is what the OP asked for: to replace not just `x` but all other names referencing the same object. In case you hadn't realised, in Python `1` is an object and in the main Python implementation everything using the value `1` is simply referencing the same object.

Comment: I should maybe add that both the old and the new object have the exact same interface, and they are both mutable (but they are completely different internally). I could probably go around and replace them manually in all lists and properties they are stored, or I could create a proxy object (probably the most sane thing, and what I should do). But I'm curious if I could just sneakily replace the object.

Comment: @Marcin: Pyjack's `replace_all_refs` is best-effort. It doesn't work reliably on strings, and I doubt it works on anything untracked by the GC. I would be astounded if it was reliable in the presence of arbitrary C extensions.

Comment: @user2357112 There's very little not tracked by the GC that you'd see in most python code.

Comment: @Marcin: `()` is untracked. `3000` is untracked. `numpy.array([1])` is untracked. There's plenty of untracked stuff in everyday Python.

Comment: Looks like `gc.get_referrers` works for untracked arguments - it just doesn't find untracked objects that refer to its argument. If you create a dict `x = {10000:10000}`, then `gc.get_referrers(next(iter(x))) == []`.

Answer (score 2):

You can put that object in global namespace of separate module and than monkey patch it when you need.

`objstore.py`:

```
replaceable = object()
```

`sample.py`:

```
import objstore

b = object()

def isB():
     return objstore.replaceable is b

if __name__ == '__main__':
     print isB()#False
     objstore.replaceable = b
     print isB()#True
```

*P.S. Rely on monkey patching is a symptom of bad design*

Answer (score 2):

[PyJack](http://pythonhosted.org/pyjack/) has a function `replace_all_refs` that replaces all references to an object in memory.

An example from the docs:

```
>>> item = (100, 'one hundred')
>>> data = {item: True, 'itemdata': item}
>>> 
>>> class Foobar(object):
...     the_item = item
... 
>>> def outer(datum):
...     def inner():
...         return ("Here is the datum:", datum,)
...     
...     return inner
... 
>>> inner = outer(item)
>>> 
>>> print item
(100, 'one hundred')
>>> print data
{'itemdata': (100, 'one hundred'), (100, 'one hundred'): True}
>>> print Foobar.the_item
(100, 'one hundred')
>>> print inner()
('Here is the datum:', (100, 'one hundred'))
```

Calling replace_all_refs

```
>>> new = (101, 'one hundred and one')
>>> org_item = pyjack.replace_all_refs(item, new)
>>> 
>>> print item
(101, 'one hundred and one')
>>> print data
{'itemdata': (101, 'one hundred and one'), (101, 'one hundred and one'): True}
>>> print Foobar.the_item
(101, 'one hundred and one')
>>> print inner()
('Here is the datum:', (101, 'one hundred and one'))
```

Comment: You should include a little more information in your post about what you're linking to.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options:

1. Design this in from the beginning, using the Facade pattern (i.e. every object in your main code is a proxy for something else), or a single mutable container (i.e. every variable holds a list; you can change the contents of the list through any such reference). Advantages are that it works with the execution machinery of the language, and is relatively easily discoverable from the affected code. Downside: more code.
2. Always refer to the same single variable. This is one implementation of the above. Clean, nothing fancy, clear in code. I would recommend this by far.
3. Use the debug, gc, and introspection features to hunt down every object meeting your criterion and alter the variables while running. The disadvantage is that the value of variables will change during code execution, without it being discoverable from the affected code. Even if the change is atomic (eliminating a class of errors), because this can change the type of a variable after the execution of code which determined the value was of a different type, introduces errors which cannot reasonably be anticipated in that code. For example

   ```
   a = iter(b) # will blow up if not iterable
   [x for x in b] # before change, was iterable, but between two lines, b was changed to an int.
   ```

More subtly, when discriminating between string and non-string sequences (because the defining feature of strings is that iterating them also yields strings, which are themselves iterable), when flattening a structure, code may be broken.

Another answer mentions [pyjack](http://pythonhosted.org/pyjack/) which implements option 3. Although it may work, it has all of the problems mentioned. This is likely to be appropriate only in debugging and development.

Comment: Good and well explained overview.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of mutable objects such as a list.

```
a = [SimpleObject()]
some_list.append(a)
b = FancyObject()
a[0] = b
```

Proof that this works:

```
class SimpleObject():
    def Who(self):
        print 'SimpleObject'

class FancyObject():
    def Who(self):
        print 'FancyObject'

>>> a = [SimpleObject()]
>>> a[0].Who()
SimpleObject
>>> some_list = []
>>> some_list.append(a)
>>> some_list[0][0].Who()
SimpleObject
>>> b = FancyObject()
>>> b.Who()
FancyObject
>>> a[0] = b
>>> some_list[0][0].Who()
FancyObject
```